# How to choose a weight function for KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am learning about the hyperparameters of a kNN model, and I came across the 'distance' and 'uniform' weight functions parameters.

My understanding is that the weight functions will be used after the model has been trained to figure out the prediction (by weighing the votes from neighbors). So my questions are the following:

Is my understanding about weight functions used only for predictions (and never during training) correct?

Seems like using 'distance' always gives close to 100% training accuracy, does this mean that using 'distance' function leads to overfitting?

When should you use 'distance' over 'uniform'?

Answer (score 2):

#### Where the `weights` parameter is being used

Your understanding of the `weights` parameter is correct, it only impacts the prediction step. It is only being used to weight the vote of each of the nearest neighbors to determine the predicted label.

To be totally precise, `KNeighborsClassifier` does not perform any training really in the first place, apart from saving the training data to memory, and therefore obviously the `weights` parameter does not come into play here.

#### Difference between `uniform` and `distance`

It is expected that using `weights="distance"` would tend to overfit more indeed. The reason for this is that it can potentially overly prioritize the closest neighbor and disregard the other nearest neighbors if they are a bit further away. `weights="uniform"` (which is the default) on the other hand ensures that even if some of the nearest neighbors are a bit further away, they still count as much towards the prediction.

This is a good illustration of the bias-variance tradeoff. Indeed, `distance` reduces the bias by down-weighting data points that are less similar, but by doing that it increases the variance since the prediction relies more on individual data points of the training sample. `uniform` does the opposite, it reduces variance by ensuring each of the nearest neighbors has the same contribution, thus reducing the dependence in individual training data points, but at the cost of equally considering nearest neighbors which can end up being still quite distant from the observation to label, which leads to larger bias in return.

To conclude, you might want to go for `distance` when you feel like your model is underfitting, which could be characterized by many "average" predictions.